# Understanding natural transformations

Tags: category-theory

I am new to category theory and quite confused about the definition of natural transformations.

The definition gives in my textbook goes as

> **Definition.** Let $F$ and $G$ be functors $\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$. A *natural transformation* $\eta$ from $F$ to $G$ consists of a morphism $\eta_X: FX \to GX$ for each object $X$ in $\mathsf{C}$. Moreover, these morphisms in $\mathsf{D}$ must satisfy the property that $\eta_YFf = Gf\eta_X$ for every morphism $f:X \to Y$ in $\mathsf{C}$. In other words, the following diagram must commute:
> $\require{AMScd}$
> \begin{CD}
> FX @>{Ff}>> FY \\
> @V{\eta_X}VV @VV{\eta_Y}V \\
> GX @>{Gf}>> GY
> \end{CD}

**Does it mean that there always exist a morphism between $F(X)$ and $G(X)$?**

For example, I have a category that has only one object $1$ and the identity morphism, I call this category $\bar{1}$. Two functors from $\bar{1}$ to the other category $\Bbb D$ are just mappings that associates $1$ to $x$ and $y$ respectively. (I do not mention the other properties that a functor has to satisfy because it is irrelevant to my question). But if in $\Bbb D$, there is no arrows between $x$ and $y$, what is the natural transformation in this circumstance?

Comment: The definition does not say natural transformations always exist.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is an explanation of why it is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: A natural transformation is a collection of arrows satisfying certain conditions. No one said such arrows should exist, we just said that we call these arrows natural when they do. More than one natural transformation can exist, sometimes, sometimes only one exists, sometimes none exist.

Comment: So if $\Bbb D$ has three objects, namely $x$, $y$ and $z$, has an arrow from $x$ to $y$ and an arrow from $z$ to $y$ and the identities. If $F$ and $G$ are functors from $\bar{1}$ to $\Bbb D$, Consider two cases, 1. $F(1)=x, G(1)=y$, then we have a natural transformation. 2. $F(1)=y, G(1)=z$, then we do not have a natural transformation.

Comment: 3. if there are two arrows from $x$ to $y$, then there are  two natural transformations for case 1? Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a morphism of functors* $F \to G$, yes there will be morphisms $F(X) \to G(X)$ for all objects $X \in \mathcal{C}$.

But there is not always a morphism $F \to G$, by exactly this fact. You have demonstrated this. Morphisms of functors neither have to be unique (regarding your "what is **the** natural transformation in this instance"), nor do they have to exist. Exactly in the same way that morphisms between objects neither have to be unique, nor do they have to exist. In fact, morphisms of functors define the morphisms in the **functor category** $[\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}]$. If $\mathcal{C}$ is the trivial category $1$, having just one object and one morphism (the identity), you can easily check that $[\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}] \cong \mathcal{D}$, so here morphisms of functors are literally just morphisms in $\mathcal{D}$. If $\mathcal{C}$ is any category, you can see morphisms of functors as morphisms in $\mathcal{D}$ that are parametrized by $\mathcal{C}$ in a "compatible way".

To get used to the concept, you should look at examples. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) and every good textbook present examples. A very good, short and basic introduction is Tom Leinster's [Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375).

*I prefer to call natural transformation **morphisms of functors** or just morphisms (when it is clear that we are talking about functors) for several reasons. (1) A general principle in category theory is the following: whenever you invent some objects, you should also define the corresponding notion of a morphism. So we write down morphisms of groups, morphisms of sets, morphisms of diagrams, morphisms of ... functors. This is just the result of trying to compare two functors. (2) The terminology "natural transformation" sounds as if something very special is going on here, but it is not. The terminology has been used by the founders of category theory to abstract from transformations in algebraic topology. Many examples of "natural transformations" are not "transformations" in the usual sense of this word, the term "morphism" however is abstract enough to cover all cases. (3) A unified terminology allows us to draw connections more easily. When I hear "morphism", I can associate to it all the theorems I know about morphisms. When I hear "natural transformation", however, I cannot *immediately* do that. For a very basic example, consider the notion that a morphism $f$ factors through a morphism $g$ if $f = hg$ for some morphism $h$. This notion applies to every morphism in every category, hence also to all morphisms of functors in functor categories. This is absolutely clear. However, the statement "a natural transformation $f$ factors through another natural transformation $g$ when ...", you have to think a bit first and probably write down something which is specific to natural transformations.

Why is this relevant to your question? I believe that a different presentation of the material, including the terminology "morphism of functors", would not have lead to the confusion which has caused your question. After all, when you see the definition of a morphism of rings, you don't get confused either by the fact that sometimes there is no morphism of rings between two given rings.